# Proof for covariant derivative property

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, general-relativity

I want to prove a statement:
$$\nabla_{\mu}A^{\mu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g} A^{\mu}).$$
I use the definition $\nabla_{\mu}A^{\nu} = \partial_{\mu}A^{\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\lambda} A^{\lambda}$, so the initial expression becomes:
$$\nabla_{\mu}A^{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}A^{\mu} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\lambda} A^{\lambda}$$ 
And I also know a property $\Gamma_{\nu\mu}^{\mu} = \partial_{\nu} \ln \sqrt{-g}$. So I try to 
$$\nabla_{\mu}A^{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}A^{\mu} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \partial_{\mu}\big[\ln(\sqrt{-g}) A^{\mu}\big].$$
And that's where I'm stuck. Please, help me out, I want to understand how it's done. I can't get rid of the first term.

**Upd**: let's follow Winther's advice and expand the right-hand side: 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g} A^{\mu}) = \partial_{\mu}A^{\mu} + \frac{\partial_{\mu} g}{2g} A^{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}A^{\mu} + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \ln g A^{\mu},$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: You have brought $A^\mu$ into the derivative in the last formula which is wrong. From what you have $\Gamma^\mu_{\mu\lambda} A^\lambda = \partial_\lambda[\log(\sqrt{-g})] \cdot A^\lambda$. To see how you should finish it up try to expand the expression $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu (\sqrt{-g}A^\mu)$ using the product rule of differentiation and compare this with what you got.

Comment: @Winther, added the derivation to the post. Got no minus sign in $\ln g$, but it's still ok, now it's clear in general. Thank you so much!

Comment: Instead of expressing the derivatives in terms of $g$ you can use that $\partial \log(\sqrt{-g}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial (\sqrt{-g})$.